# Is there a name for the technique where a singer uses the falsetto register on releasing a note?

Tags: voice, terminology

As per the title, is there a name for the technique where a singer (especially a female one) voices a pitch in the falsetto register on releasing a note?

Examples include:-

- Alanis Morissette

  - *You Oughta Know* - particularly at the end of the chorus, "You^ You^ You^ Oughta Know"
- Sinead O'Connor

  - *Nothing Compares to You* - occasionally "since you been gone I can do whatever I wa-aaa-aan^t" around 45s
- Dolores O'Riordan from The Cranberries

  - *Zombie (The Cranberries)* - constantly... "Z-om-bi^e, Z-om-bi^e, Z-om-bi^e e^eh e^eh e^eh o^oh o^oh" etc

Comment: I'll add more examples if I find some. I'm listening to all sorts of embarrassing 90s pop looking for more!

Comment: In German, I'd call it _umkippen_ (“tip over”) or _kieksen_ (onomatopoeic). The closest fit in English might be just _the voice cracks_, but that seems rather more severe...

Comment: While I know exactly what you mean, you might want to find a description for this other than *falsetto,* because you’re talking about female singers, and it’s controversial whether female falsetto exists.

Comment: Yes.  It's called "yodeling."  (Sorry, couldn't resist)

Answer (score 3):

I think the technique is best described as a [yodel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yodeling), which is defined as a quick flipping between vocal registers. A yodel isn't specific to the release of a note, but is the closest thing to a proper term for the general technique.

If you're trying to describe the style for a someone, "like a yodel" might be clearer, since most people associate yodeling with a more specific genre of music/vocalization.

Like leftroundabout mentioned, it could also be described more informally as a voice crack in some scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it can also be described as 'Keening' or a song style used in the old days after a death- a form of vocal lament for the dead.
Dolores' voice, yodeling or not is beautiful.